# Selecting Where PDF Files Save

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm so relieved that I finally got the code below to work with the help of this community.

I have one more option on my wishlist that I'm struggling with. Currently, the code below will save worksheet 3 all the way to worksheet titled "post" as separate PDF files into a folder I select. This is triggered by a shape.

**I'm trying to make the below code prompt a folder select so users can select where their PDF files are saved, does anyone have any ideas how to do this?**

Also, the Call Shell at the bottom would preferably open the folder where the files are saved, but that's not really necessary as long as users know where the files are being saved :)

```
Sub SaveAllPDF()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Fname As String
Dim TabCount As Long


TabCount = Sheets("Post").Index
'Set the TabCount to the last cell you want to PDF

' Begin the loop.

For i = 3 To TabCount
'Set i = the number of the first sheet you want to PDF in order from left to right To TabCount
    If Sheets(i).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then
    Else
        With Sheets(i)
            Fname = .Range("C15") & " " & .Range("E13") & "-" & .Range("B1")
            'The Fname above is equaling the cells that the PDF's filename will be
            'The folder directory below is where the PDF files will be saved
            .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\operation automated\RLtemp\" & Fname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End With
    End If
Next i

Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\operation automated\RLtemp\", vbNormalFocus)
'This opens the folder where the PDFs are saved
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the Excel's [FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx) object:

```
Sub SaveAllPDF()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim TabCount As Long

    TabCount = Sheets("Post").index
    'Set the TabCount to the last cell you want to PDF

    Dim dialog As FileDialog
    Dim path As String

    Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    dialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If dialog.Show = -1 Then
        path = dialog.SelectedItems(1)
        ' Begin the loop.
        For i = 3 To TabCount
        'Set i = the number of the first sheet you want to PDF in order from left to right To TabCount
            If Sheets(i).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then
            Else
                With Sheets(i)
                    Fname = .Range("C15") & " " & .Range("E13") & "-" & .Range("B1")
                    'The Fname above is equaling the cells that the PDF's filename will be
                    'The folder directory below is where the PDF files will be saved
                    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=path & "\" & Fname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
                End With
            End If
        Next i

        Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & path & "\", vbNormalFocus)
        'This opens the folder where the PDFs are saved
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the 400 error message that pops up if you hit cancel on the Browse folder selection?

Comment: @user3026842 - Oops, slight oversight.  I *knew* there was I reason I was checking the return value...  See the edit.

Comment: blaaah genius man. thank you! I work in a office environment that relies heavily on excel and just started tinkering with VBA a few weeks ago.. so amazing how much you can automate. again thanks!